# unable to get city name from geo location

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, geolocation

i am using following code to get country and city name

```
<?php 
    $user_ip=  getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    $geo= unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));

    $city= $geo["geoplugin_city"]; 
    $country= $geo["geoplugin_countryName"]; 
?>
```

when i echo it prints  country name but for city it says

```
Undefined index: geoplugin_city
```

using `var_dump` for `$geo` i get `[geoplugin_city]`  in array but when i `var_dump($city) i get null`

Please help me with this

this is my var_dump($geo) result

```
Array ( [geoplugin_request] => 83.110.15.6 
        [geoplugin_status] => 206 
        [geoplugin_credit] => Some of the returned data includes GeoLite 
                              data created by MaxMind, available 
                              from http://www.maxmind.com. 
        [geoplugin_city] => 
        [geoplugin_region] => 
        [geoplugin_areaCode] => 0 
        [geoplugin_dmaCode] => 0 
        [geoplugin_countryCode] => AE 
        [geoplugin_countryName] => United Arab Emirates 
        [geoplugin_continentCode] => AS 
        [geoplugin_latitude] => 24 
        [geoplugin_longitude] => 54 
        [geoplugin_regionCode] => 
        [geoplugin_regionName] => 
        [geoplugin_currencyCode] => AED 
        [geoplugin_currencySymbol] => Dh 
        [geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8] => Dh 
        [geoplugin_currencyConverter] => 3.6719 )
```

Comment: Show us `var_dump($geo);` Just show.

Comment: Why `geoplugin_city` key can't be null?

Comment: seeign my value please check how do i get my city  from this ?

Comment: Sometimes geoplugin does not provide  city name. Use $city= !empty($geo["geoplugin_city"])?$geo["geoplugin_city"]:'N/A';

Comment: This is `print_r`, if you use `var_dump` - you'll see that `geoplugin_city' => string '' (length=0)` so it's an empty string.

Comment: @AmitKumar now it says not available so cant i use it ?

Comment: It totally depends on Geoplugin if it providing city name then use it otherwise you will display N/A , You can not get city name from somewhere else  if it does not provided by Geoplugin.

Answer (score 1):

It happen because `GeoPlugin` return you **status 200** it means City information not available for your country.

Like if you try this IP: **119.30.127.20 (Pakistan)**

It will return you `status 200` with city and state fields empty.

**But when you try this IP: 168.143.160.187 (USA)**

It will return you `status 206` with city and state information.

Here is the index of status:

```
[geoplugin_status] => 200
```

For more detail visit [GeoPlugin Web Services](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices) and check your country information either city level information provided or not.

> **UPDATE:**
>
> GeoPlugin is only provide **3%** city level information for **UAE**

Comment: @Sikander: visit to link that i have provided. u will get the idea.